# Json 3 dimensional array to PHP

Tags: php, json, azure-cognitive-services

i'm using Microsoft Emotion Api and it return a result as a json. so i want to access emotion values and assign that values to php variables. i used json_decode function but it can't do it. 
result like below

```
[  
  {
    "faceRectangle": {
      "left": 63,
      "top": 94,
      "width": 66,
      "height": 97
    },
    "scores": {
      "anger": 0.00300731952,
      "contempt": 2.18678448E-08,
      "disgust": 9.284124E-06,
      "fear": 0.0001912825,
      "happiness": 0.9874571,
      "neutral": 0.0009631537,
      "sadness": 1.887755E-05,
      "surprise": 0.008223598
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this if you want it as an array

```
$array = json_decode($var, true);
```

Otherwise it will return the json as a object instead of an array

Doing this should let you access it like so:

```
$fl = $array[0]['faceRectangle']['left'];
```

Comment: You're missing the variable name and the first array dimension.

Comment: @Barmar Haha, good point.

Comment: You're still missing the first dimension. Did you notice that the objects are in an array?

Comment: Nope, slipped right past my eyes.